# How to create a git repo containing already existing repo?

Tags: git

Okay so I have a directory structure like this:

```
/srv
|
+--website
   |
   +--www
   +--nginx
```

in `/srv/website` I have a `docker-compose.yml` that spins up Nginx (using config in `/srv/website/nginx`) and PHP-FPM that runs files in `/srv/website/www`.

The directory `/srv/website/www` *is already* a git repo.

I want to create a git repo for `/srv/website` that treats `/srv/website/www` as a ... subtree? submodule? Not sure the term ... but in essence, I want to commit everything except `/srv/website/www` into this new repo, while referring to the 'other' repo for the `www` subdir.

How do I do that?

---

### Update 1

So I just went ahead and do this:

```
cd /srv/website
git init
git submodule add $URL_TO_REPO_OF_www www
git commit -m "Initial Commit + Submodule"
git add .
git commit -m "Working as of $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")"
git remote add origin $URL_TO_REPO_OF_website
git push -u origin master
```

When I check on GitLab, I see that the `www` folder is now a link to "the repo for www", like so:

[image: Subdir "www" is a link to the other repo]

Was the way I did it wrong? Will there be any problems?

Comment: Why not use a `.gitignore` file to exclude `www` and then add `www` as a subtree _or_ submodule (that points to your `www` repo)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+nested+repositories

Comment: @phd I've searched lots of answers on S.O., all that I found asked about "creating new blank repo _then_ adding a subtree/submodule underneath". My situation is "here's a tree, one of the subdirs is a repo. Make a repo on the higher level."

Comment: 1st you have to decide if you want to just ignore `www` and treat it as a separate independent repository. Or you want to include it somehow into the parent repo. You can include in different ways: remove `www/.git/` and commit. Use submodules or subtrees.

Comment: A Git repository *cannot* contain another Git repository. It's forbidden. It can *refer to* another Git repository ("submodule"), or you can remove the "inner" *repository* entirely so that there are just some files left, or do something else to get rid of the inner repository. But those are your options.

Comment: @torek I've updated my question with things I just did out of desperation. "Seems" to work so far. Do you think there will be problems in the future with how I did it?

Comment: That looks correct. Submodules *do* work, but they have annoyances; but all approaches here have some sort of annoyance, so you have to pick which ones you are willing to live with. I think you'll get as good use out of this as anything...

Comment: @torek okay thanks. Well, a bit of annoyance is to be expected with a non-simple layout like this :D ... if it becomes too annoying in the future, I'll rethink my approach. At least now I can properly version-control the whole tree ;-)